# Set bold the text of IconTabFilter

Tags: css, sapui5

I would like set a **Bold** style only for the text of one IconTabFilter
For example in this view https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBarNoIcons/preview I want for example **Notes** and **Info** in bold
It is possible?
What is the class property that i must change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't do it. `iconTabFilter` not have `addStyleClass` methods borrowed from class `sap.ui.core.Control`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a simple css style to your app.

.sapMITBFilter {
  font-weight: bold;
}

That is it. :) have fun.

Comment: .sapMITBFilter { font-weight: bold; } set all my iconTabFilter text to bold; I would like add a my personal class to only one iconTabFilter, but it not have addStyleClass methods borrowed from class sap.ui.core.Control